# Structure of lists in `for` loop w.r.t `rnorm` in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am doing a simple exercise involving vectors and lists. It revolves around just generating 10 random values drawn for each given value of the mean from a normal distribution. The exercise involves a simple use of a `for` loop:

```
mu = c(-10, 0, 10, 100)

random_norm = vector(mode = "list", length = 4)

for(i in seq_along(mu)){
  random_norm[i] = rnorm(n = 10, mean = mu[i])
}

random_norm
```

The output I expected was a list of length 4 where each entry in the list would be a vector containing 10 values for each of the respective means used to generate the values, i.e:

```
[[1]]
[1] - vector of length 10

[[2]]
[1] - vector of length 10

etc
```

But instead I'm getting the error:

```
#> Warning in random_norm[i] <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = mu[i]): number of items to
#> replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

So I deduce it must be something I'm misunderstanding with regards to the structure of vectors and lists. Could somebody explain what is going wrong?

Comment: Use `random_norm[[i]] <- ...`. You were using the wrong assignment function.

Comment: I was thinking about that...so using the `[[` allows me to drill into each component of the list instead of a list in a list....I see now... thanks.

Comment: FWIW, perhaps a more direct generation: `random_norm <- lapply(c(-10, 0, 10, 100), rnorm, n = 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's really pretty hard to search SO for prior answers on this topic. There are two fundamental assignment operators for lists: `[[<-` and `[<-`. The first assigns the value into a list "package". The second tries to assign it as.is. Since it was a vector of length 10 it can’t be a proper sub-list.

Technically that was only a warning. That code did produce a list of length 4 but it only had the first item in each of the 10 element vectors.